# mapping dictionary keys to Mysql database table columns

Tags: mysql, pandas

I need help to figure out how to map dictionary keys with my MySQL Database Table columns.

I want to insert dictionary keys values in my MySQL Database Table columns and i believe that i have to do correct key-column mapping first before inserting values or it will fail & might succeed with data corruption.

Any help or links how to do is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which library are you using to talk to the MySQL? The question is tagged with pandas. If so, have you checked pandas.to_sql: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: for e.g my dictionary keys {"fname":"john","lname":"Davis","custid":12345, "City":"Houston"}
MYSQL Database Table Column Names (firstname,lastname,customerID,cust_city)

My question is how i can do the mapping of keys with my table columns to insert respective key values in my table. please help.

Comment: I understand but how you name your keys in the dict is mostly irrelevant here as you are inserting the values not the keys. That's why I am asking which library you are using to perform the insert. I will provide an answer using pandas and you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an SQLAlchemy engine to talk to your MySQL database you can use pandas.to_sql to do insertion easily.

Here is a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('...')  # fill in the connection string

# generate the list of customer dicts
cust1 = {"fname": "john", "lname": "Davis", "custid": 12345, "City": "Houston"}
cust2 = {"fname": "jane", "lname": "Elvis", "custid": 67890, "City": "NewYork"}
customers = [cust1, cust2]

# convert to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(customers)

# reorder columns so that it is the same as the table
df = df[['fname', 'lname', 'custid', 'City']] 

# Do the insert
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: i am using SQLAlchemy & will do quick testing & will let you know. thank you again for your help, Gani.

Comment: getting following error.

ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

Comment: Can you share a code snippet so we can better help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you using Sqlalchemy then `bulk_save_objects` would be a lot faster than `pandas.to_sql`

```
s = Session()
objects = [
    Customer(fname="john"), # map your dict to the ORM class object
    Customer(fname="jane")
]
s.bulk_save_objects(objects)
s.commit()
```

http://www.devx.com/dbzone/optimize-inserts-using-sqlalchemy.html